# Unpredictable "Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl35' were found." when dynamically adding controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I understand that this question has popped up countless times but none of the posts I can find have been able to help me with this issue.

Every once in a while, I receive the error in the title: `Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl35' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.` This certainly does not happen all the time, and it seems that simply refreshing a few times will cause the error to go away.

My page essentially has an `UpdatePanel` and in it, the user is meant to enter data corresponding to parts of an order. Since there can be multiple parts, there is a button that creates a new `Panel`, creates input fields and adds it to the `Panel`, and then adds it to the `UpdatePanel`. A user can click this button multiple times to add multiple entry `Panel`s. In order to accomplish this, I maintain a `List<Panel>` which I add the new `Panel` to every time the user wants a new entry field. When the page receives a postback (from the add button), I then iterate over the List and re-add each `Panel` to the `UpdatePanel`, which manages to persist the existing entry Panels.

Since these fields are dynamically updated, I made sure to set the IDs of the fields that I'll be retrieving data from to those that will be unique and distinguishable from each other. However, as mentioned, I will occasionally run into issues about finding multiple controls with an ASP.NET auto-generated ID (`ctl35` in this case). Looking at the rendered HTML in Chrome once I receive this error, there simply are no controls that have `ctl35` as their ID. Furthermore, none of the rendered HTML even contains any elements whose IDs end in the auto-generated "ctlXX". Because of this, I can't understand where a possible named conflict issue can come in. The fact that this error doesn't occur most of the time also is a major source of confusion here.

Any ideas on what this issue may be, or what I might need to do in order to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are assigning ID's to all dynamically created controls, not just those you need to get data from. I've seen this happen when using default ID's on the added controls.

Comment: Seems that the problem was a combination of what you said and another issue. Indeed, putting IDs on every single control made this error never appear. However, there was still another issue at the root of it which was somehow causing the behavior that this issue only appeared rarely.

When we took the site offline (via `asp_offline.htm`) and re-enabled the site, the issue was guaranteed to show up. Seems like there was something wrong with caching, perhaps? I'm not sure, but at least this solves the problem. If anyone can shed insight into that, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: If you look at a control, the HTML id assigned to it is a combination of the names from ALL of the parent controls (unless you change the ClientIdMode property in v4). If any of those names change, the client controls cannot map back to the server side controls. That could be what you are seeing with the offline/online process.

Comment: All of the generated IDs that belong to the dynamic controls are prefixed with `ctl00$MasterContentHolder$`, and this has never changed, though that was a good idea. It still just seems odd that the error occurred on the second postback (i.e., adding a second Panel). Oh well, if I have more time I can further investigate but since the error is essentially fixed, I'll just move on. Thanks for the help!